# How to stop EXCEL asking: "Are you sure you want to install this customization?"

Tags: excel, installation, customization, comsol

Whenever I open EXCEL, Microsoft Office Customization Installer asks me to if I want to install a specific customization (COMSOL).

How can I stop this?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAkOE.jpg)

Thanks!

Comment: Try to look [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1463f103-01a4-4b45-82d5-b689ac1127d0/microsoft-outlook-addin-security-warning-issue?forum=vsto)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b6229b5a-fa1e-4eea-ac24-80260ed1bb6c/how-to-stop-a-popup-for-install-customization-excel-plugin?forum=vsto

So it's basically deleting a registry key which can exist in one of 4 possible locations:

Try either **HKEY_CURRENT_USER** or **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE** as starting points.

Then check **Software > Microsoft > Office > Excel > Addins** and **Software > Wow6432Node > Microsoft > Office > Excel > Addins** and delete the subfolders under Addins that belong to the Addin you want to silence Excel asking about. Worked for me in Win7 / Excel2013